# Why when I use cast to create a date and set it to a mysql variable is it stored as a BLOB?

Tags: mysql, variables, casting, hex

When I run this MySQL command:

```
SELECT @nullDate := CAST('2000-01-01' AS DATE) AS nullDate
```

the result is `323030302d30312d3031` (a hexadecimal value)

What I would expect is `'2000-01-01'`
What is going on here?  This is a problem, because I need to perform `date_add` on this value, and when I do that, the result of that operation is also hexadecimal. I need a readable date string.  So far my googling hasn't help me find a solution.

Comment: Have you confirmed that this actually causes a problem?  I see the same behavior, but date/time math with the variables works fine for me, because the resulting blob is just the bytes of the characters in `2001-01-01`, which is close enough to a date that the server should subsequently treat it as such.  In MySQL,  user-defined variables can't have a type of date/datetime, they're strings without a character set/collation... a blob.  I think your *client* is "helpfully" showing you the hex characters, but `LENGTH(@nullDate)` is really 10, not 20.  This is the hex representation of your string.

Comment: When I used DATE_ADD with the result, I always get NULL. The code is actually much more complicated than what I'm showing you, but I've distilled out this piece, since it is the essence of my problem.

Comment: Start with a clean connection and run the code you've shown here.  Does `DATE_ADD()` using this variable work after that?  The "much more complicated" may indeed be much more of a complicating situation, so we need an MCVE here to illustrate the behavior of `DATE_ADD()` not working with the variable.

Comment: This code: 
`SELECT @nullDate := CAST(  '2000-01-01' AS DATE ) AS nullDate, DATE_ADD( @nullDate , INTERVAL 1 YEAR )`
produces this result set:
323030302d30312d3031
323030312d30312d3031
The result of DATE_ADD is not null, so maybe there's something that can be done with it.  How would I make that human-readable as a date?

Comment: What client are you using to run this? And what is your server version (`SELECT @@VERSION;`)? `SELECT CAST(DATE_ADD( @nullDate , INTERVAL 1 YEAR ) AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8)`.

Comment: This totally works: 
`SELECT @nullDate := CAST( CAST('2000-01-01' AS DATE) 
 AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8 ) AS nullDate, CAST( DATE_ADD( @nullDate , INTERVAL 1 YEAR ) AS CHAR
CHARACTER SET utf8 )`  and it looks like the key to the solution of this problem. I was unaware of the ability to set character set in CAST.  Thanks, Michael - sqlbot!

Comment: by the way, regarding your question about the client, i was testing this stuff mostly in phpMyAdmin. The version of MySQL is 5.1.73.

Comment: Yes, I suspected as much, on both counts.  MySQL 5.1 was trying to be "correct" and not treat user defined variable values as strings unless it "knew" they really were strings of real characters (as opposed to just bytes). Later versions aren't quite as obsessive though I have never investigated what led to the behavior change.  And phpMyAdmin is trying to be "helpful" by showing you a blob as hex. If you used your original query in code, it would have been fine -- PMA is causing a distraction with its blob display handling.  Using the `mysql` CLI you should see the original expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You must to convert the Char into date like this:

```
SELECT @nullDate := STR_TO_DATE('2000/01/01', '%Y/%m/%d') AS nullDate
```

Comment: Sorry? I didnt understand

Comment: a related question is this:

`Why in MySQL does 
SELECT @nowDate :=  '2001-01-01' AS nowDate, DATE_ADD( @lastDonationDate , INTERVAL 1 YEAR ) AS oneYear
return a record set of 
2001-01-01, null
instead of
2001-01-01, 2002-01-01`

Comment: this also produces a null value where there should be a 2002-01-01

`SELECT @nowDate :=  '2001-01-01' AS nowDate, DATE_ADD( CAST( @lastDonationDate AS DATETIME ) , INTERVAL 1 YEAR ) AS oneYear`

Comment: your code throws a syntax error in mysql, though i wouldn't be surprised if it worked in some other flavor of sql.